# Angular Material Autocomplete custom template - group items

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am building a website which requires the Autocomplete to load results from ajax, so I decided to choose the angular material Autocomplete and its working fine.

Until now my requirement was to show the search results of one type, lets say I need to show the search results of country names, but now my requirements changed to show the country names and the state name and this cause me to make two different groups one of country and the another of state, i did not found a solution of show to modify the angular material autocomplete custom template.

Please see the image attached:

[image: results required like inimage]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have create one solution which can help you.
Please find link 
[Angular Material Autocomplete custom template](https://jsfiddle.net/wrs05t5w/4/)

Here the logic is, find out first element in the searched list and add country name on it

```
var states = getStates().filter(function(item) {
                    item.isFirst = false;
                return (item.state.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText.toUpperCase()) !== -1);
            });
            var countryName = "";
            angular.forEach(states, function(item, key){
                 if(countryName != item.country){
                    countryName = item.country;
                  item.isFirst = true;
               }
            })
```

You have to work on styling part line adding divider between values. 
Please let me know if I can help you in other context

Comment: Hi Durgaprasad Budhwani,
Well thanks for providing me the solution but unfortunately it is not working as expected, i dont want the Country names to be selectable moreover the search for the state names is also not working properly, can you please dig more for a perfect solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi consider this version, modified solution from above answer if it helps, 
https://jsfiddle.net/sachinshukla5/9xykgvs6/78/

Basically just adding an additional element in the items array which is needed to be dispalyed at specific index.

```
var states = getStates().filter(function(item) {
                        item.isFirst = false;
                    return (item.state.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText.toUpperCase()) !== -1);
                });
                var countryName = "";
                angular.forEach(states, function(item, key){
                     if(countryName != item.country){
                        countryName = item.country;
                      states.splice(key,0, {
                      "isFirst" : true,
                      "state": " ",
                      "country": countryName
                    });
                   }
                })
                deferred.resolve(states);
            }, 200);
```